# How to store my query sql to array in vb.net

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, vb.net, arraylist

I've tried to read data to an array or arraylist using `MySqlDataReader` to this code:

```
    Dim list As New ArrayList()

    Dim id_analysis As String = Data_Analysis.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value
    cmd = New MySqlCommand("Select ID_sub from tb_data_analysis where ID_process = '" & id_analysis & "'", conn)
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    While reader.Read()
        list.Add(reader("ID_sub").ToString())
    End While
    For Each num In list
        MsgBox(num)
    Next
```

It's not working, producing no data in `num`. How should I approach this? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe there is no data in the database matching your select? Have you tried debugging this? Also it's better to use List(Of String) instead of ArrayList.

Comment: There is a fair amount which could be improved (SQL PArameters, disposing of the db objects you create); but it is possible that there is no matching record

Comment: This code will be vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: @Saragis Thank you so much .It's work for this code. ^O^